# DAX DynamoDB Cache in .Net?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-dax

I know DAX is relatively new, but I've been trying to find some documentation on how to implement the client in my .net application. All of the examples shown in java make it seem really easy. You just replace the AmazonDynamoClient with the AmazonDaxClient.

However, when I import the latest AWSSDK.DAX nuget package it doesn't seem to function like this. Can anyone point me to a tutorial or show me an example of how to easily replace the DynamoDBClient with a DAX one in C#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good news! .NET support for Amazon DynamoDB Accelerator (DAX) is now available!

Here's the official announcement: 
https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/02/amazon-dynamodb-accelerator-dax-releases-sdks-for-python-and-dot-net-support-for-t2-instances-and-now-available-in-the-asia-pacific-singapore-and-asia-pacific-sydney-regions/

and you can find links to the code here: 
http://dax-sdk.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/

Enjoy and let us know if you have more feedback!

Answer (score 3):

We are actively working on DAX client for .net, that will be just as easy as the Java client.

Comment: Do you have any idea what kind of time frame we're looking at with that?

Comment: .Net SDK for DAX was just [released](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/02/amazon-dynamodb-accelerator-dax-releases-sdks-for-python-and-dot-net-support-for-t2-instances-and-now-available-in-the-asia-pacific-singapore-and-asia-pacific-sydney-regions/), check it out

Comment: I can't find any example how to initialize ClusterDaxClient with dax:// URL and when I'm trying to use that class it raises error: No endpoints found!